# How to convert feature matrix to feature vector in image processing?

Tags: image, matlab, vector

I have an image with `256*256` dimensions and after feature extraction, with `gabor-filter`, I have another `256*256` matrix as a feature. So how can I convert this matrix to a vector(not by reshape)?

I mean for a database of `10000 images`, if I use reshape procedure then I can't compute it with a computer because the size of the data will be so big.
I need this for the learning process.

So how can I convert a `256*256` matrix to a small vector like `1*300` or `1*1000` without losing data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple methods exists to extract the useful information with Gabor filters. One of the possibilities is to calculate the (local) average of the absolute value or squared value of the filter output. You can make a trade-off between how locally you calculate the average and how many Gabor filters you use. This completely depends on your use case. For example, if you have rather homogeneous images, taking the average of the complete filter output may be useful.